# Discriminant of a basis

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

I am trying to find the discriminant of the Q-basis $ ( 1,\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{9}) $ . I want to do it by explicit matrix computations. I know that I have to find embeddings, but I think there is only one embedding, Because the minimal polynomial for each element has repeated roots, so the  determinant is zero. I don't know what is my mistake. I was wondering if somebody help me.

Comment: Your basis is a power basis, so you can use the Vandermonde determinant to compute the discriminant.

Comment: I can not find the true matrix. All the rows are equal.

Comment: What's the degree of your number field over $\Bbb Q$? Do you know how many embeddings of your number field into $\Bbb C$ this guarantees you?

Comment: I just know the degree is 3 and I need three embeddings.

Comment: Right, but I think you're confusing embedding with $\Bbb Q$-automorphism of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{3})$. Since $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{3})/\Bbb Q$ is not Galois the terms don't coincide.

Comment: Why do you say the minimal polynomial has repeated roots? The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is $X^3 - 3$. And yes as @ÍgjøgnumMeg mentioned, the embeddings of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$ into $\mathbb{C}$ are not necessarily $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$.

Comment: Yes,  it has 3 different roots in $  \C $. it has two conjugates $ \sqrt [3] {2} \omega $ and $   \sqrt [3] {2} \omega^2 $ . Thanks for your helps.